# Initilialising an array of objects that contain an array of other objects?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am trying to declare an array of buildings but the floors associated with each building are never initialised. I want to provide values to the data members for each instance of floor that is associated with each instance of building:

```
class Floor
{
    public int number;
    public int rooms;   
    //constructor
    Floor()
    {
        rooms = 5; 
        number= 0;           
    }
}

class Building
{
    public Floor[] floors= new Floor[6];
}

public partial class frmF2 : Form
{
    Building[] x = new Building[7];
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can use a constructor, right?

Comment: new Floor[6] is creates array of floors, not 6 Floor objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But it is very ugly.

```
class Building
{
    Building()
    {
      floors = new Floor[6];
      for(int i=0; i<6;++i)
          floors[i] = new Floor();
    }

    public Floor[] floors;
}
```